# The VPC vpx-xxxxxxxx associated with the default subnet group does not exist

Tags: amazon-rds, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

Modifying an existing Elastic Beanstalk installation I was trying to create a Postgres database using RDS and got the error message:

"The VPC vpx-xxxxxxxx  associated with the default subnet group does not exist. 
Please delete the default subnet group or specify another subnet group."

I had looked in AWS, VPC, Your VPCs and had not found vpc-xxxxxxxx.
I thought the error message was referring to a deleted/hidden setting.

Answer (score 2):

There are also VPC settings under RDS, Subnet groups.

I was able to Delete the offending vpc-xxxxxxxx and Create DB Subnet group.

Then I was able to create the database as expected.